# X-Frame Options set as "DENY DENY"

Tags: security, header, http-headers, same-origin-policy, x-frame-options

In some web applications I have noticed there are to options set for X-Frame options header like

X-Frame-Options: DENY DENY

(DENY option should have been wrongly added twice).

In this case, will the browser obey to such header as it is obeying for

X-Frame-Options: DENY.

or else will it eliminate this header option as meaningless by considering "DENY DENY" as meaningless

if it is obeying, what will happen for scenarios like

X-Frame-Options: DENY SAMEORIGIN

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Browsers handle `X-Frame-Options: DENY DENY` as if it were just `X-Frame-Options: DENY`.

Safari previously [had a bug that caused it to ignore `X-Frame-Options`](https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=113387) if it had a duplicate value, and Chrome inherited [the same bug](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=145659). And Firefox also previously [had pretty much the same bug](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=761655).

But they’ve since all been fixed: They behave the same as they would if the value was given once.

> if it is obeying, what will happen for scenarios like
>
> `X-Frame-Options: DENY SAMEORIGIN`

For that case, [what Mozilla ended up implementing](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=761655#c4) (and Safari and Chrome ended up following) is:

> use the most restrictive policy… if the framing situation violates any of them, blocks the load

Thus the browser behavior for `X-Frame-Options: DENY SAMEORIGIN` is `DENY` (most restrictive).

So, unfortunately while there is no authoritative spec to point to on what the required behavior is if there are multiple values for the header—because [the `X-Frame-Options` spec, RFC 7034](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7034) doesn’t actually state what the requirements are—in practice, the current Safari/Chrome/Firefox behavior is the expected behavior. Not sure what IE/Edge does, but if it’s different from Safari/Chrome/Firefox on this, then that’d be a bug that would need to be fixed in IE/Edge too.